# Return empty fields in view if relationship not available?

Tags: sql, laravel

I am trying to retrieve a view with a employee and personal detail data that are held on different tables. It works fine when the relationship is set.

However when employee model does not yet have a PersonalDetail row in db i get Trying to get property of non-object for the personal detail data. How do i write my controller so that it ignores null fields and returns empty fields to my blade? Code:

Employee Model

`public function PersonalDetail()
    {
   return $this->hasOne('App\PersonalDetail');
    }`

PersonalDetail model

```
 public function Employee()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
}
```

And my controller

```
 public function show($employee )
{
    $employee = Employee::find($employee); 
    $personaldetails = $employee->PersonalDetail;
    return view('employees.show')->withEmployee($employee)->withPersonalDetail($personaldetails);
}
```

example blade item

```
{{ $employee->personaldetail->address }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to just check is is `null` or not:

```
{{ $employee->personaldetail ? $employee->personaldetail->address : '' }}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to change it level above the view then you can add a method in the `Employee` model like this:

```
public function getPersonalDetailAddress()
{
    return $this->personaldetail ? $this->personaldetail->address : '';
}
```

and then in the view:

```
{{ $employee->getPersonalDetailAddress() }}
```

Comment: Is there a way I could do it from controller? or model?
I want to have as few lines as possible in view blade.

Comment: Add this line instead of  {{ $employee->personaldetail->address }} line

Comment: Thanks. Works now.